# 'cabal run' gives "unrecognised command: run"

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-dev

I'm attempting to create simple Cabal executable package.

The [Cabal user guide](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#running-executables)'s "Running executables" section says:

> You can have Cabal build and run your executables by using the run command.
>
> ```
> cabal run EXECUTABLE [-- EXECUTABLE_FLAGS]
> ```

Yet when I enter that command:

```
$ cabal run HelloWorld
```

I get this error message:

```
cabal: unrecognised command: run (try --help)
```

`cabal --help` tells me that, indeed, there is no `run` command.

**Am I missing something? How do I run my executable?**

---

I'm totally new to Haskell and Cabal; please let me know what info would be helpful to include here.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.5.

`cabal --version` gives:

```
cabal-install version 0.14.0
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library
```

`ghc --version` gives:

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your version of cabal-install is too old. The newest version of cabal-install is 1.20. You can upgrade to this version by running `cabal install cabal-install`.

Comment: Thank you! In case useful for OS X users, it seems I _had_ already run `cabal install cabal-install` but without realizing that the upgrade got installed into `~/.cabal/bin/cabal`, different from Homebrew's original installation location `/usr/local/bin/cabal`. Doing `export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH` cleared that issue.

Comment: After running "cabal install cabal-install" and successfully installing "cabal-install-1.20.0.2", I still have "cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library". Why?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Perhaps you do not have `$HOME/.cabal/bin` in your `$PATH`; or perhaps your shell requires a `rehash`.